# Composite Components in subfolders

Tags: jsf, composite-component, myfaces

I am experiencing a problem with a composite component. I'm not quite sure if it's a bug in one of the used libraries or just my own ignorance of the matter. If I put the component bar.xhtml files in

```
WebContent/resources/foo/bar.xhtml
```

everything is working as intended. But if I put them in

```
WebContent/resources/subfolder/foo/bar.xhtml
```

they are just not displayed, and I get the message:

> The page /login.xhtml declares namespace http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/subfolder/foo and uses the tag foo:bar , but no TagLibrary associated to namespace.

I suspect it has something to do with the unmapped resource handler from Omnifaces, and is maybe just a parameter I'm not able to figure out. Maybe someone can give me a hint here?

I'm using (amongst others):

- Apache MyFaces 2.2.4
- Omnifaces 1.8.1
- Primefaces 5.0
- Tomcat 8.0.12

**Edit 2**
Moved the answer to a reply

Comment: Just disable the `UnmappedResourceHandler` to exclude it from being the cause.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I was pretty sure I tried that yesterday. But now it didn't do anything to the cause. However, I found the solution (which I will edit into the question). Sometimes it helps to just go to sleep and check the problem again the next day.

Comment: That's great. But you should not put the answer in the Question, rather post it as an Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok - after sleeping one night over it, I found out that this had nothing to with Omnifaces, but with a change in MyFaces since 2.1.6. Since then, you have to put the following in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_JSF_2_ALLOW_SLASH_LIBRARY_NAME</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

(found [here](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/myfaces-users/201304.mbox/%3C1e7063b6.3e457e16.51768711.dd58c@o2.pl%3E) )